# Is there a way to require a non-image asset in react-native new asset system?

Tags: javascript, ios, assets, react-native, packager

In react-native 0.14, we can `require` an image using `const fireImage = require('./images/demo.jpg')`. The `require` works fine with images(png, jpeg, gif), 'js' and 'json' files.

My question is: Is it possible to 'require' a '.mp3' or '.mp4' files?

I have tried the 'mp3' file and the Xcode reported a build error like this

```
uncaught error Error: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module ./music/some from /Users/rongshen/tmp/react-native-test/imageTest/index.ios.js: Invalid directory /Users/rongshen/tmp/react-native-test/imageTest/music/some.mp3
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you have any luck?

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else running across this post that's still trying to figure it out, you can utilize the `rn-cli.config.js` file to add additional file types for the `require()` method.

Example, add a file named `rn-cli.config.js` to the project root with the following contents:

```
module.exports = {
    getAssetExts() {
        return ['mp3', 'mp4']
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to play the mp3 file, I would recommend using [React Native Sound](https://github.com/zmxv/react-native-sound)